# AVSpeechSynthesiser bugging ViewDidLoad function

Tags: swift, xcode, avfoundation, avspeechsynthesizer, avspeechutterance

Whenever I navigate to this view controller, the `speakText()` function in `viewDidLoad` for some reason doesn't work and the view controller takes a long time to load (this is not the case when I remove that line). Above that line, a text label's text is set to the string that is meant to be spoken, and works fine. Each time `recordTapped` is called, the speech synthesis works perfectly. However, it just doesn't seem to work in `viewDidLoad`.

*UPDATE* I have done some more testing, after assigning the view controller delegate of the speech synthesiser and running the function asynchronously. However, it doesn't work. I set the view controller to initial view controller and it still doesn't work, so it isn't a problem in navigation and load time is still very long.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class StartViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioRecorderDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!
    let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
    var myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "")
    var number = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        synth.delegate? = self as! AVSpeechSynthesizerDelegate
        number = 0
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async       {self.speakText(int: number)}
        self.number = self.number + 1
    }

    @IBAction func recordTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        speakText(int: number)
        number = number + 1
    }

    func speakText(int: Int) {

    myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "the number is \(int)")
    myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "en-AU")
    synth.speak(myUtterance)

    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please try using multithreading for your speech needs? You are calling speech from Main thread, probably that is posing an issue. Try with global -> userInteractive/ userInitiated queues, and let me know if it works.

Comment: Also try setting Speech's delegate to the Vc (self) before calling that within viewDidLoad() and then check.

Comment: Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in the comments, multithreading works. Just tested myself. Working code below, please test and confirm. It is always good to rely on separate thread for speech.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var recordButton: UIButton!

    var number = 0

    @IBAction func recordTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        questionLabel.text = "\(number)"
        speakTest(int: number)
        number += 1
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        number = 0
        questionLabel.text = "\(number)"
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated).async {
            self.speakTest(int: self.number)
        }
//        speakTest(int: number)

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    func speakTest(int: Int) {
        let utterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: "Number is \(int)")
        let synth = AVSpeechSynthesizer()
        synth.speak(utterance)
    }
}
```

**Plus**, To call Speech whenever view appears, call it from `viewWillAppear()` or `viewDidAppear()` and not from `viewDidLoad()`, since the latter is called once when the app is in foreground.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated my question as it still isn't working.

Comment: Did you use GCD? Was working on my end. Thanks for the update though. Will check

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by GCD, however, the view controller takes a long time to load, but only the first time. Once I navigate to the previous view controller and return to it, it loads instantly.

Comment: Updated question again incorporating your code, maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: viewDidLoad function will not be called again and again whenever you switch viewControllers. 
viewDidAppear gets called that way. Try having the speech function called from viewDidAppear/ viewWillAppear and let me know if it works.

Comment: When a view is loaded into memory, it is not let go unless there is no reference reaching to it. Since you are talking about switching between ViewControllers, reference of previous VC is still within the new VC. Meaning, viewController doesn't get reloaded again, it "appears". Hence use the func within viewDidAppear or viewWillAppear please.

Comment: Got a chance to try from viewDidAppear?